# Find indexes of elements in an array equal to sum - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the indexes of element in an array equal to a specified sum.
I only want 2 indexes.

```js
function sumArrayHashTable(arr, sum) {

  var result = [];
  var hashTable = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var S = sum - arr[i];

    if (hashTable[S] !== undefined) {
      result.push([arr[i], S]);
    } else {
      hashTable[arr[i]] = arr[i]
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(sumArrayHashTable([5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 9, 0], 9));

//Result should be [[2,4], [5,6]]
```

I am able to print the numbers but not the indexes. Please advice

Comment: shouldn't `[1,2,3]` and `[0,2,4]` be part of the result set?

Comment: Sorry. I need only 2 indexes. Edited the question.

Comment: so `i` is your index, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, i is the index

Comment: `I am able to print the numbers but not the indexes` - those indexes are your `i`s

Comment: I tried replacing arr[i] with i, didnt work

Comment: *"I want it using a Hash Table"* why? how? what do you mean when you say hash table, as you're not hashing anyting in your code? And what benefit do you expect from doing so?

Comment: what's the expected output for `sumArrayHashTable([1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1], 3)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your hash table to store the indices instead of the values. Also, push the indices in your result array:

```js
function sumArrayHashTable(arr, sum) {

  const result = [];
  const hashTable = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    const S = sum - arr[i];

    if (hashTable[S] !== undefined) {
      result.push([i, hashTable[S]]);
    } else {
      hashTable[arr[i]] = i;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(sumArrayHashTable([5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 9, 0], 9));

//Result should be [[2,4], [5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumArrayHashTable(arr, sum) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var test = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (i === j) {
        continue ;
      }
      test = arr[i] + arr[j];
      if (test === sum) {
        result.push([i, j]);
      }
    }  
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(sumArrayHashTable([5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 9, 0], 9));
```

Result will be `[[2,4], [5,6]]` plus `[[4,2], [6,5]]` you can take it from now

alghorithm is simple, `O(n^2)` - loop over array once, then again and find sum that equals 9

Comment: I want it using a Hash Table.

Comment: @a2441918 so apply hash table to my answer dude, or specify your question