# How to use javascript to get the element value to match sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are two array and sum is 9.

What it will return only true or false

i.e.:

array1[1,2,4,9] sum=9 return false

array2[1,2,4,5] sum=9 return true

It needs two number in array to match the sum.

What i try in my JS:

```js
function hasPairWithSum(arr, sum) {
    var len = arr.length;
    for(var i =0; i<len-1; i++) {
        for(var j = i+1;j<len; j++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] === sum)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(hasPairWithSum([1, 2, 4, 9], 9));

console.log(hasPairWithSum([1, 2, 4, 5], 9));
```

Well,I want a different way to reach the goal

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find indexes of elements in an array equal to sum - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544761/find-indexes-of-elements-in-an-array-equal-to-sum-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution is this

```js
function twoSum(arr, S) {

  var hashTable = {};

  // check each element in array
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // calculate S - current element
    var sumMinusElement = S - arr[i];

    // check if this number exists in hash table
    // if so then we found a pair of numbers that sum to S
    if (hashTable[sumMinusElement.toString()] !== undefined) {
      return true;
    }

    // add the current number to the hash table
    hashTable[arr[i].toString()] = arr[i];

  }

  // return false as default
  return false;

}

console.log(twoSum([3, 5, 2, -4, 8, 11], 7));
```

It uses hash tables

Answer (score 1):

```js
function ContainsSum(arr, sum) {
  return arr.some((n, i) => arr.some((m, x) => n + m === sum && i != x))
}

console.log(ContainsSum([1, 2, 4, 9], 9));
console.log(ContainsSum([1, 2, 4, 5], 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using a **generator function** and recursion to generate the pairs, and an `includes` function that takes an iterator and a predicate and extracts items from the generator to test them against the predicate:

```js
function* getPairs(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) return false;
  const [h, ...tail] = arr;
  for (let v of tail) {
    console.log(`[${h}, ${v}]`);
    yield [h, v];
  }
  yield* getPairs(tail);
}

function includes(iterator, predicate) {
  let result = iterator.next();
  while (!result.done) {
    if (predicate(...result.value)) {
      return true;
    }
    result = iterator.next();
  }
  return false;
}

const sumEquals = sum => (a, b) => a + b === sum;
const pairEquals = ([a, b]) => (i, j) => a === i && b === j;

console.log(includes(getPairs([2, 4, 9]), sumEquals(9)));
console.log(includes(getPairs([2, 4, 5]), sumEquals(6)));
console.log(includes(getPairs([2, 4, 5]), pairEquals([2, 5])));
```